# Book about Ruby on Rails with Apache2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, controller

I used to use the Webrick server for Ruby on Rails, but now my boss asked me to run the ROR code on apache server, I see there are some difference between these two servers, and I don't know how to access the controller/action on apache, so anyone happens to know any book about ROR on apahce? Thx!

Answer (score 3):

To run directly in Apache, your best bet is to use [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com), which can act as an Apache module.

---

However, I think you're missing a bit of conceptual information as well.  Here's some of the common Rack servers used to host rails:

**WEBrick**: A web server implemented purely in Ruby (that ships with Ruby).  It is not very performant, and is relatively limited.  It makes for a great development webserver, but most people don't use it in production.

[**Thin**](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin): A very performant evented web server that is particularly easy to get up and running.

[**Unicorn**](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/): A forking web server that is widely used and recommended (written by GitHub) - but requires a bit more management to get up and running in production.

**In nearly all cases**, however, people generally have Nginx or Apache in front of their Rails webserver of choice (as a proxy):

- Nginx/Apache do a much better job of serving static files than any of the options above.  If you are not using a CDN to host your assets, you should definitely configure the proxy to host them.
- Nginx/Apache are great at managing large volumes of requests and queueing them so that your app server can focus on in-flight requests rather than a deluge of queued-up requests.
- Less surface area for security vulnerabilities.

*My configuration of choice is Nginx+Unicorn; I find Apache too unwieldy to administrate, and Unicorn is particularly great.*

Comment: Excellent answer indeed; more answers on SO should be this thorough and complete.